# Получение размера LinearLayout из атрибутов

Tags: android, java

Здраствуйте!
У меня есть класс `Round`, который расширяет `LinearLayout`. Как мне в конструкторе из `AttributeSet attrs` получить его высоту и ширину в пикселах?

```
<Round
    android:id="@+id/gameField"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.28"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</Round>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструкторе никак.

Размер станет известен только после того как пройдет вызов `onMeasure` или по простому после того как система примерит лэйаут к реальному экрану с учетом соседних элементов, ориентации экрана и проч.

Comment: спасибо, придумал другое решение)